# Spring Security - Need to add custom cookies

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am new to Servlets. I need to generate the custom value cookie. In mention below code the session cookie is generated but I need one more with custom value.

```
public ServletContextInitializer servletContextInitializer() {
    servletContext -> servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig().setName("sessiondemo");
}
```

My Servlet code is as below. In the comment line I need to add cookies. Basically I am redirect the request which comes here to init the servlet session in mean time I also need to generate a cookie with name hello and value world in servletcontext.

```
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
    UserDetails user;

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextInitializer servletContextInitializer() {
        /* This code doesn't work here. I need to use here to set up the cookie
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("YourCookieName", "CookieStringValue");
        cookie.setMaxAge(10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60); // set cookie for 10 years
        response.addCookie(cookie); */
        return servletContext -> servletContext.getSessionCookieConfig()
                .setName("oneKosmosIdpSessionId");
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
    protected static class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private IdpConfiguration idpConfiguration;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/metadata", "/favicon.ico", "/api/**", "/*.css",
                            "/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/fonts/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/user.html", true)
                    .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(new AuthenticationProvider(idpConfiguration));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have renamed the session tracking cookie, usually  `JSESSIONID` to `sessiondemo`. What to you mean by custom value?

Comment: means I have to create one more cookie let say flag= "true". I don't want to delete this sessiondemo cookie need one more additional to it.

Answer (score 1):

The sessionCookieConfig class is used to change the general cookie setting for the Servlet Engine.

Since you are using Spring Security, session management is handled by Spring. So, you don't really need cookies. If you need to store any User level parameters then store it in your own implementation of Spring's `UserDetails` Object and retrive it in the view.

> This tag allows access to the current Authentication object stored in
>   the security context. It renders a property of the object directly in
>   the JSP. So, for example, if the principal property of the
>   Authentication is an instance of Spring Security's UserDetails object,
>   then using  will
>   render the name of the current user.
>
> Of course, it isn't necessary to use JSP tags for this kind of thing
>   and some people prefer to keep as little logic as possible in the
>   view. You can access the Authentication object in your MVC controller
>   (by calling SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication())
>   and add the data directly to your model for rendering by the view.

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html

Comment: @Priyanka Kanse did you check the `authentication` tag?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to generate the custom value cookie.

You can create a cookie with a custom value by adding this code to your servlet like so:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("YourCookieName","CookieStringValue");
cookie.setMaxAge(10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60); //set cookie for 10 years
response.addCookie(cookie); //add cookie to response
```

Comment: where did you try it? How is it not working? Have you checked your browsers cookies to see if it is there?

Comment: I have posted the code Kindly look into this @Jonathan

Comment: yeah i can see why it doesn't work there @PriyankaKanse. You are not in a servlet, so there is no response. You need to use that code in a servlet (where the class extends HttpServlet) and you have doPost/doGet methods.

Comment: How can I use it here as it is required.and I am using springbok with theamleaf.

Comment: how is this class being called? From where?